# MVC checkbox tree

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone point me in the direction of how to read the inputs from a tree of checkboxes?

So, bearing in mind that there are a variable number of checkboxes, what I would like to do is have a controller that looks like this:

public ActionResult Edit(int id, string name, int[] selected)

Where selected contains an array of id numbers representing which checkboxes were checked.

At the moment I'm having to read HttpContext.Request.Params and rely on my checkboxes having the unique names "Selected[1]" and "Selected[2]".  I can't rely on the order of the controls, as my integer number represents an entity Id.

Then the next thing I'd really like is to have the parameter be a ViewModel, rather than individual parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var i in Model)
{    
   <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@i.ItemId" /><br/>
}
```

will bind exactly as you say:

```
public ActionResult MySubmitAction(int[] selected)
{
   ...
}
```

it will be an array if ID's of the items you selected

Comment: Thanks Chris (great name btw).  Have also pushed the parameters into a view model, and reduce the overall noise of the code.  Much more elegant now.